# Can't install ruby gem on macOS Sierra10.12.6 even with rvm or sudo

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

Trying `gem install json-schema` on the command line results in

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - connect(2) for "192.168.1.1" port 53`

I'm on a Mac which reports macOS Sierra 10.12.6.
I have Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b).

I have rvm installed, and I'm using ruby 2.2.9. I get the same behavior with ruby 2.5.0. Same deal if I try to `sudo gem install json-schema`. Same thing if I try `sudo gem install json-schema -n /usr/local/bin`

If you're wondering why I haven't upgraded to High Sierra yet, it's because my coworkers have, and let's just say it has not gone well for them. :/

Comment: That's weird - have had no issues upgrading to HS nor have my coworkers.  That's odd that it's trying to do DNS lookups against that address; is that the main router for your network?

Comment: Yes, this is the main router for my home network